Title of a movie with monster and a squad
I am searching the title of a movie i've watched long time ago. I remember that there was a lot of monsters capable to bond into a sphere and a squad of people armed against that evil. In the team there was a member able to change the aspect transforming himself from man to women. Did anyone know the title?
Edit
I saw the movie about 20 years ago. I think that the years of the movie was about '80. I think i saw that on VHS or on italian TV.

Any more details that may help identification? When did you watch it (apart from a "long time ago")? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Anything else you might remember?

What language was it in?  Was it live action or cartoon?  Where did you see it (cinema, TV)?

Could it be Critters 2 (1988)? Near the end of the movie there is a scene where the critters form a giant critter ball and go on a rampage, rolling through the town.
Two of the protagonists are shape-shifting bounty hunters (Ug and Lee).  They start out somewhat neutral-looking, but one of them transforms into a man, and the other transforms into a beautiful woman.
Here is a clip on Youtube of the Critterball:



And here are the bounty hunters:


This isn't really a long time ago, but you're not thinking of the 2010 Indian film, Robot, are you?
Not only is it terrific fun, it has a baddie that multiplies and turns into a giant, death-dealing sphere. If I recall, I think he even turned into a woman at one point.


I thought the question was a joke for the film "monster squad" !
monster squad wiki

Taking ID as a joke, now who will save you from my rage ;) .....Anyways, can you expand your answer, why you think its a match.

cos of the words monster and squad
